# Using a composite template

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm trying to figure out when I need to set a sequence order# for a server template and whether I need to do the same for a composite template. Here is the problem I'm trying to address: my envelopes will have 3 or 4 documents, each document will have its own template. I will have inline templates for each document, it will be the same signer roles on each document. If I have multiple document/template pairs in an envelope, does that mean I have to use a composite template? If I am using multiple server templates for a doc, for example, is that when the sequence order is important? I just need to understand these composite templates more.

Comment: Compositing templates together are powerful, sophisticated, and sometimes complicated feature. If you can make it to San Francisco in May, we'll have several sessions on it.

Comment: I sure wish I could go. Any chance you folks have something in NYC? I might be able to swing that, but SF is probably out of the question.

Comment: We're planning additional documentation and info on compositing templates. The SF conference is aimed at DocuSign developers and is free for developers. See https://momentum.docusign.com/san-francisco2017/en/developer-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If I have multiple document/template pairs in an envelope, does that mean I have to use a composite template?

Yes.

> If I am using multiple server templates for a doc, for example, is that when the sequence order is important?

Sorry I'm not an expert on this yet. There are several StackOverflow questions about Compositing Templates, check them out.

Also, what's best is to try out a test envelope. If it doesn't work the way you expect, then ask a new, specific, question about your code.

Answer (score 1):

You must use composite templates.  The sequence of the documents in the envelope will follow the structural sequence of your `compositeTemplate` elements.

Each `compositeTemplate` element has one or more `serverTemplates` and/or `inlineTemplates`.  Each template element of those arrays has a `sequence` element with an integer value.  These values should form a sequence within that composite, and determines the order in which a document is derived for the composite and the order of overwriting that takes place for other envelope elements.

The document contributed to the envelope by a single composite is either explicitly provided via the `composite::document` node, or if not present, by the first (lowest sequence value) template within the composite that can contribute a document, such as a `serverTemplate` document or an `inlineTemplate::documents` node.

Overwriting envelope elements follows the "last in gets final overwrite" approach. Thus the value specified in the last (highest) `sequence` template overrides all previously set values.